# Valid preprocessor tokens in macro concatenation

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I tried to understand the macros in c using the concatenation preprocessor operator ## but I realized that I have problem with tokens. I thought it was easy but in practice it is not.

So the concatenation is for concatenating two tokens to create a new token.
ex: concatenating `(` and `)` or `int` and `*`

I tried

```
#define foo(x,y) x ## y
foo(x,y)
```

whenever I give it some arguments I get always error saying that `pasting both argument does not give a valid preprocessor token.`

For instance why concatenating `foo(1,aa)` results in `1aa` (**which type of token is it ? and why it is valid**) but `foo(int,*)` I got an error.

Is there a way to know which tokens are valid or is it possible to have some good link to understand how can clarify it in my mind. (I already googled in google and SO)

What am I missing ?

I will be grateful.

Comment: Asking for links is off-topic. And you may receive help if you actually show what you passed to cause that error.

Comment: I think `1aa` is not a valid preprocessing token

Comment: it doesn't belong to any 6 tokens types but gcc says nothing about it not even a warning ?

Comment: @mm: `1aa` is a [preprocessing number](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.8); it is a valid token for the preprocessor. (A pp-number can have any sequence of identifier characters after the digits, as is evident from the lexical grammar in the standard.)

Answer (score 6):

Preprocessor token concatenation is for generating new tokens, but it is not capable of pasting arbitrary language constructs together (confer, for example, [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html)):

> However, two tokens that don't together form a valid token cannot be
>   pasted together. For example, you cannot concatenate x with + in
>   either order.

So an attempt at a macro that makes a pointer out of a type like

```
#define MAKEPTR(NAME)  NAME ## *
MAKEPTR(int) myIntPtr;
```

is invalid, as `int*` are two tokens, not one.

The example of above mentioned link, however, shows the generation of new tokens:

```
 #define COMMAND(NAME)  { #NAME, NAME ## _command }

 struct command commands[] =
 {
   COMMAND (quit),
   COMMAND (help),
   ...
 };
```

yields:

```
 struct command commands[] =
 {
   { "quit", quit_command },
   { "help", help_command },
   ...
 };
```

Token `quit_command` has not existed before but has been generated through token concatenation.

Note that a macro of the form

```
#define MAKEPTR(TYPE)  TYPE*
MAKEPTR(int) myIntPtr;
```

is valid and actually generates a pointer type out of `TYPE`, e.g. `int*` out of `int`.

Comment: so concatenation is taking two tokens to create a new existing token right ?

Comment: what about foo(1,foo) it generates 1foo is it an identifier ? and thanks again. and please if possible the expansion of arguments ? does it occur or not ?

Comment: `1foo` is a token, but not a valid identifier for a variable declaration, for example. So even if token concatenation yields a valid token, this does not guarantee that this token can be used in any context then.

Comment: And concerning argument extension: Docu says: "As with stringification, the actual argument is *not* macro-expanded first."

Comment: 1foo cannot be neither an identifier nor a keyword so how can the preprocessor know if it is a **valid** token. what is the definition of **valid token** ? (thank you for the expansion I also found the same thing in gnu compiler documentation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133323/discussion-between-stephan-lechner-and-sabrina).

Answer (score 4):

Since it seems to be a point of confusion, the string `1aa` is a valid *preprocessor* token; it is an instance of `pp-number`, whose definition is (§6.4.8 of the current C standard):

```
     pp-number:
            digit
            . digit
            pp-number       digit
            pp-number       identifier-nondigit
            pp-number       e sign
            pp-number       E sign
            pp-number       p sign
            pp-number       P sign
            pp-number       .
```

In other words, a `pp-number` starts with a digit or a <kbd>.</kbd> followed by a digit, and after that it can contain any sequence of digits, "identifier-nondigits" (that is, letters, underscores, and other things which can be part of an identifier) or the letters <kbd>e</kbd> or <kbd>p</kbd> (either upper or lower-case) followed by a plus or minus sign.

That means that, for example, `0x1e+2` is a valid `pp-number`, while `0x1f+1` is not (it is three tokens). In a valid program, every `pp-number` which survives the preprocessing phases must satisfy the syntax of some numeric constant representation, which means that a program which includes the text `0x1e+2` will be considered invalid. The moral, if there is one, is that you should use whitespace generously; it has no cost.

The intention of `pp-number` is to include everything which might eventually be a number in some future version of C. (Remember that numbers can be followed by alphabetic suffixes indicating types and signedness, such as `27LU`).

However, `int*` is not a valid preprocessor token. It is two tokens (as is `-3`) and so it cannot be formed with the token concatenation operator.

Another odd consequence of the token-pasting rule is that it is impossible to generate the valid token `...` through token concatenation, because `..` is not a valid token. (`a##b##c` must be evaluated in some order, so even if all three preprocessor macros expand to <kbd>.</kbd>, there must be an attempt to create the token `..`, which will fail in most compilers, although I believe Visual Studio accepts it.)

Finally, comment symbols `/*` and `//` are *not* tokens; comments are replaced with whitespace before the separation of the program text into tokens. So you cannot produce a comment with token-pasting either (at least, not in a compliant compiler).

Comment: An interesting consequence of the lax syntax for `pp-number` is `1_000` **is** a valid `pp-number`, which makes `_` an ideal candidate for an optional thousands' separator while preserving compatibility with many existing tools. It is sad to see the C++ alternative `1'000` make its way into the C standard as this questionable alternative breaks almost all existing tools.

Comment: @chqrlie: Absolutely. The design of C++ has never been friendly to tooling; it's almost as though they decided to frustrate any attempt to syntax highlight, for example. Mind you, the preprocessor had already made accurate tooling difficult. The use of `1'000` as a separator was definitely another annoyance (although it's in common use in Colombia and probably other places, so there's some kind of precedent).

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessing token is defined by the C language grammar, see section 6.4 of the current standard:

> ```
> preprocessing-token:
>                    header-name
>                    identifier
>                    pp-number
>                    character-constant
>                    string-literal
>                    punctuator
>                    each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
> ```

The meaning of each of those terms is defined elsewhere in the grammar. Most are self-explanatory; `identifier` means anything that is a valid variable name (or would be if it wasn't a keyword), and `pp-number` includes integer and floating point constants.

In Standard C, the result of pasting two preprocessing tokens must be another valid preprocessing token.  Historically some preprocessors have allowed other pasting (which is equivalent to not pasting!) but this leads to confusion when people compile their code with a different compiler.

Comment: so what about `1aaa`?

Comment: Using  `##`  is not recommended.

Comment: I can't find out why foo(-,1) fails, as -1 would be an integer.

Comment: @StephanLechner `-1` is two tokens, `-` (unary negation operator) and `1`. There are no negative integer constants

Comment: What about `#define concat3(a,b,c) a##b##c`... does `a##b` have to be a valid token or can we paste `concat3(.,.,.)` successfully on all conforming implementations?

Comment: @chqrlie suggest posting a new question

Comment: @chqrlie: according to (both) standards, the order of application of `##` is unspecified and depending on an order is UB. In practice, every implementation I know of does it piecemeal left to right, so `a##b` must be a valid token. It's impossible to construct `...` with token concatenation.

Comment: @M.M: I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68330439/can-we-paste-3-tokens-using-the-c-preprocessor-operator

Answer (score 0):

First one need to understand what is tokens in C 
Tokens are the smallest elements of a program, which are meaningful to the compiler.

Here is the List:
Tokens can be classified as follows:

```
Keywords
Identifiers
Constants
Strings
Special Symbols
Operators
```

Let take the below Programme

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define concat(front, back) front ## back
int main() {
    printf("%i\n", concat(123, 456));
}
```

**Output:** 123456

Above program worked as 123456 is of type int and a constant value

Lets Modify the Program

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #define concat(front, back) front ## back
    int main() {
        printf("%s\n", concat(aa, 1));
    }
```

The above will produce below error:

```
error: ‘aa1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   47 |     concat(aa, 1)
      |            ^~
```

aa1 is a valid preprocessor token, and a valid identifier but one that is not defined that's what compiler is complaining about ‘aa1’ undeclared

To fix the error , if I just define aa1  like below

```
 char aa1[] = "hello World"
  or 
 #define aa1 "Hello World"
```

Then it just work Fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define aa1 "Hello World"
#define concat(front, back) front ## back
int main() {
    printf("%s\n", concat(aa, 1));
}
```

Output: Hello World

Now try `concat(aa1, aa1)`, it will still produce valid preprocessor token, and a valid identifier but `aa1aa1` that is not defined

try `concat(, aa1)`  // assuming `aa1` is defined

I hope above explanation helps.

Comment: You might want to expand a bit and say that `aa1` is a valid preprocessor token, and a valid identifier but one that is not defined in the second program. You should also explain that `1aa` is a valid preprocessor number, but not a valid C token. A third example with `concat(a,1aa)` producing `a1aa` would illustrate this oddity, assuming you define `a1aa` properly.

Comment: @chqrlie Update my Answer please have a look thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your modification addresses the first part of my comment...